# Konjunktiv 2 mit Modalverben

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb

Haben die zwei folgende Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung?

> Wenn Mark den Bus nicht verpasst hätte, hätte er nicht den ganzen Weg laufen müssen.
>
> Wenn Mark den Bus nicht verpasst hätte, müsste er nicht den ganzen Weg laufen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nein, sie haben nicht die gleiche Bedeutung. Der erste Satz nutzt den Konjunktiv II der Vergangenheit im Hauptsatz, der zweite nutzt den Konjunktiv II der Gegenwart.

Im ersten Beispiel hat Mark den Bus verpasst und musste bereits den ganzen Weg laufen (und hat es wahrscheinlich auch getan). Im zweiten Beispiel hat Mark den Bus zwar bereits verpasst, aber das Laufen des Weges (oder genauer: die Notwendigkeit, den Weg zu laufen) geschieht jetzt oder in der Zukunft (futurisches Präsens). Mark läuft läuft also in diesem Moment den ganzen Weg oder wird es bald tun.